# Migrating from SQL Azure to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, cloud, database-migration

As we all know there are lots of tools to migrate the database from SQL server to SQL Azure with schema & data..but is there any way to migrate an SQL Azure database to a SQL server with data?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the database migration tools are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh694043.aspx) in great details and please follow the link at the bottom section name "Migrate between SQL Databases" and here you will see the following tools described with installation guidance along with screenshot to explain how to use them:

1. Data-tier Application DAC Package
2. Data-tier Application BACPAC Packag
3. Generate Scripts Wizard
4. bcp
5. SQL Database Migration Wizard
6. SQL Server Integration Services
7. SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
8. SQL Server Migration Assistant

As most of above tool runs on your local machine (a few of them are running in cloud as well) so once you have connectivity established between your desktop and SQL Database, you can backup data from one side to other side, means from SQL Database to SQL Server Database or vice versa.

Comment: The above guide has been updated and only explains how to migrate from SQL Server to Azure, not the reverse.